# Which solvent is good for using SU-8 particle in Optical tweezers?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, solvents

I'm studying Optical tweezers. I've used Polystyrene for samples. Nowadays, I've got SU-8 pillar. I wanna use that for sample, but its density is heavier than water. I can't use that. So I wanna know some liquid for replacing water.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some experiments recently with SU-8 and polistirene and figured it out, that SU-8 solvent melts polistirene. Just wanna say, that this won't work out well.

But to use something instead of water: why not using alcohol (ETOH) or isopropyl. I use the last as much as possible since it's not leaving any stains on stuff I do.